# Codeigniter form validation callback function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, validation, callback

I've written a simple callback function which isn't working. My other callbacks (which are in the same library file) work fine so I guess the problem has to do with my code.

The parameter passed in the callback function takes the form of a chunk of PHP which is eval()'ed to form part of an 'if()' statement in the function itself.

Here's what's in the controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rating', 'Rating','required');
$condition = $this->input->post('rating')  . " != 'Excellent'";
$this->form_validation->set_rules('details', 'Details', 'required_conditional[' . htmlentities($condition) .']');
```

And here's the callback function itself:

```
function required_conditional($str, $condition)
{
    if (eval(html_entity_decode($condition))) {
        if ($str == '') {
            $this->set_message('required_conditional', 'The %s field is required');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it's not working anyone?

Thanks, Matt

Comment: mind to post some examples of $condition?

Comment: See the second line in the first code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `eval` evaluates statements, not expressions.  This will give you a parse error:

```
$test = "1 > 0";
if (eval($test)) { echo "echo!"; }
```

And this will work as you expect it to:

```
$test = "return 1 > 0;";
if (eval($test)) { echo "echo!"; }
```

Comment: OK, so in the case of my example above, I should change $condition to:

    return $this->input->post('rating')  . " != 'Excellent'";

??

I'd actually created a simplified example there. What I really need to do is this:

    $condition = "('" . $this->input->post('exterior_condition_rating')  . "' != '-1') && ('" . $this->input->post('exterior_condition_rating')  . "' != '5 - Excellent')";

so how would I get that to work?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise the line breaks would be stripped out. Hope it's still readable!

Comment: `$condition = "return ('" . $this->input->post('exterior_condition_rating') . "' != '-1') && ('" . $this->input->post('exterior_condition_rating') . "' != '5 - Excellent');"`

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't you use "`callback_<function name>`" ?

Comment: I've extended the validation class and included the function in there so there's no need to use the callback_ prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Yep the correct syntax to call form validation callbacks it to use "callback_"